# PHP preg_match_all strange behaviour with "/" character

Tags: php

Using :

```
preg_match_all(
    "/\b".$KeyWord."\b/u", 
    $SearchStr,
    $Array1,
    PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

This code works fine for all cases except when there is a `/` in the `$KeyWord` var. Then I get a warning and unsuccessful match of course.

Any idea how to work around this?

Thanks

Comment: Problem is resolved, I appreciate every bit of information you guys provided. My database has diverse values, so I chose "~" as delimiter. Still I got not match when there was a "/" at the end of the URL (Maybe a bug?) 
For now, I drop the ending "/" and things are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

use `preg_quote()` around the keyword.

https://www.php.net/preg_quote

but also provide your delimiter, so it gets escaped: `preg_quote($KeyWord, "/")`

Comment: Thanks, but when I use preg_quote, although I don't get the warning message I don't get a match either!

Answer (score 1):

You must parse $KeyWord and add "\" before all spec symbols, you can use preg_quote()

Answer (score 1):

### Dynamic Values In Patterns

You are using a dynamic value inside the pattern. Like escaping for SQL or HTML, a specific escaping for the value is needed. If you do not escape meta characters inside the value are interpreted by the regex engine. The escaping function for PCRE patterns is `preg_quote()`.

```
preg_match_all(
    "(\b".preg_quote($KeyWord)."\b)u", 
    $SearchStr,
    $Array1,
    PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
);
```

### Delimiters

The syntax of a pattern in PHPs preg_* function is:

```
DELIMITER PATTERN DELIMITER OPTIONS
```

The / is the delimiter in your pattern. So the / inside the $keyWord was recognized as the closing delimiter.

But all non alphanumeric characters can be used. In Perl and JS you can define a regular expression directly (not as string) using / so it is often the default in tutorials.

Most delimiters have to be escaped inside the pattern.

- Match a \:  `'/\//'`

The exception to this rule are brackets. You use any of the bracket pairs as delimiter. And because it is a pair, they can still be used inside the pattern.

- Match a \: `'(/)'`

The () brackets are a good decision, you can count them as "subpattern 0".

Comment: greetings, the information was useful still I can not locate a url like `https://serverx.forexample.com:2083/` in the string!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to handle the backslash character.

From the manual:

> puts a backslash in front of every
>   character that is part of the regular
>   expression syntax

You can also pass the delimiter as the second parameter and it will also be escaped. However, if you're using `#` as your delimiter, then there's no need to escape `/`

So, you can either use:

```
preg_match_all("/\b".preg_quote($KeyWord, "/")."\b/u", $SearchStr,$Array1,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
```

or, if you are sure that your keyword does not contain any other regex-special characters, you can simply change the delimiter, and use to escape the backslash:

```
preg_match_all("#\b".$KeyWord."\b#u", $SearchStr,$Array1,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
```

Comment: Not escaping the keyword, because you are using "a different" delimiter is bad. What if the keyword contains '#'? Also any Regex-Like expression will mess it up. ALWAYS escape strings, when using inside a regex.

Comment: I know.. I provided him both the options, and explicitly told him that escaping `/` can be avoided by changing the delimiter, in particular.. That was an extra info.

Comment: but also extra wrong... $KeyWord = "where?" - and your regex will match "wher" also... No delimiter involved, but wrong result.

Comment: I do not understand you. Look carefully, my answer uses the same function as does your answer.

Comment: anyways, I updated my solution to state the use case for the second code, if that is what you are referring to. :)